# ¿Cómo iterar un array de a 3 valores para insertar en una tabla en SQL?

Tags: c#, sql

Quiero insertar un Array String a una tabla de SQL.

El array que tengo tiene grupos de 3 valores (nombre, edad y ubicación), uno tras otro:

```
string[] aux = new string[]{"Carlos","25","Mexico","David","18","Puebla","Laura","30","Queretaro","Monica","28","Monterrey","Ricardo","26","Mexico","Maribel","31","Sonora"};
```

Y en SQL tengo una tabla llamada "Informacion" con las columnas "NOMBRE, EDAD, UBICACION" a la que quiero agregar estos valores.

¿Es posible ingresar los primeros tres registros del array a las 3 columnas de una fila, y después los siguientes 3, y así sucesivamente hasta finalizar el array?

Se supone que podría utilizar un foreach para leer el array e insertar pero quiero iterarlo en grupos de a 3 y no sé cómo. Estoy sin encontrarle solución a este código

```
foreach (string str2 in myarray1)
{
    var mycommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO informacion VALUES(@NOMBRE, @EDAD,@UBICACION)", myConnection);
    mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NOMBRE", str2);
    mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EDAD", str2);
    mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UBICACION", str2);
    mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: que quiere decir 3 y luego 3?

Comment: o sea, ese codigo no funciona... bah, definitivamente mirandolo no funciona...

Comment: Edité la pregunta según la entendí y me parecía más claro. No dudes en modificarla de nuevo o comentar si hay algo mal.

Comment: Te comento por aqui.. para darte las gracias gbianchi y Mariano se que es incorrecto pero registre mi pregunta como usuario invitado y no la pude comentar.. Si eso es lo que me faltaba por entender ya que me habian comentado que no era posible hacer un insert de esa manera y me quede con esa duda. Gracias.

Comment: Me alegro que te haya servido... No te deja porque no mantuviste las cookies del navegador...

Answer (score 3):

Debes iterar el string no usando un for each, si no recorriendolo de a tres, usando un for comun

```
for (int i = 0, i < aux.length(), i=i+3)
{
    var mycommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO informacion VALUES(@NOMBRE, @EDAD,@UBICACION)", myConnection);
    mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NOMBRE", aux[i]);
    mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EDAD", aux[i+1]);
    mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UBICACION", aux[i+2]);
    mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```